# Auto upload documents to sharepoint from outlook attachments

Tags: email, outlook, office-integration, attachments

I'm looking for an out of the box solution to auto upload outlook email attachments to SharePoint and sending them as links instead of actually attaching them as files to emails.

I heard about 3rd party outlook plugins that could do just that and an open source alternative (Outlook connector) but I need some sort of comparison, do you have any idea about that?

Comment: i assume you already discarded the use of "Incoming email" in SharePoint? Beyond the fact that "links to files" would be really a head-banger with regards to where would you store those files to point to them as links?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is an out of the box option to achieve this in SP2010.  However, SP2013 may provide a means to achieve your requirement out of the box:
  - Drag attachments to SharePoint Site Mailbox Document Library
  - Drag attachments from SharePoint Site Mailbox to a new email message (adds links)

There are a few limitations/restrictions but it may meet your requirement: see White Paper for some more info on Site Mailboxes: http://www.scinaptic.com/sharepoint-2013-site-mailboxes.html

As you mentioned, there are number of 3rd party products of which the free OnePlaceMail Express or Enterprise edition is one (Note: I'm directly connected with this product).

The following video shows replacing attachments with links in an email...
http://youtu.be/1aEkLfVOYcU

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using Outlook 365? you can download Sharepoint Connect app from Microsoft Apps Store 
https://store.office.com/sharepoint-connect-WA104379267.aspx

You can upload email and attachments to Sharepoint from Outlook